# Algebraic Minimizing: why repeating a minterm?

Tags: boolean-algebra

I'm studying minimizing boolean expressions using adjacent expressions...

However I'm not understanding this example

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqPZv.png

Why are they repeating minterms? Why is this correct? When can I do this? Shouldn't the function be the sum on the minterms 0,1,3, 5 and 7 only ONE time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to include term 5 also.

The repetitions happens just because of the simplification process, is not on purpose.

Comment: Right, I forgot to write that... But my doubt is about repeating term 1...

Comment: It happens just because of the simplification process, is not on purpose. Can you write a simpler expression which does not include repeated terms?

Comment: I think not, I tried not to include that term... It's like we're applying idempotency, right? But on reverse?

Comment: ...that could be a way to look at it